# Is it possible to run nightly cargo with stable rustc

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In our project we need to use an unstable cargo option `--out-dir`, but we still want to use stable rustc to build our rust code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to [configure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) the nightly `cargo` executable to use the stable `rustc` compiler by modifying the `build.rustc` key. You could delegate this to the stable compiler if `rustup` is installed by setting the value to be `rustup run stable rustc`.

Comment: The doc says `build.rustc` should be a path to `rustc` program. How do find where `rustc` is stored?

Comment: @Nowibananatzki the docs do not explicitly say so, but from the key's default value (`"rustc"`) and the existence of environment variable overrides, it looks like `build.rustc` can be any string which, when passed to a shell, would invoke the rustc compiler. If you have `rustup` in your `PATH`, setting the `build.rustc` key to `rustup run stable rustc` should delegate the cargo's compiler call to rustup, which would in turn delegate it to the installed stable rustc if my assumption is correct. The actual path of the `rustc` executable will depend on the installation medium (rustup, apt, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `__CARGO_TEST_CHANNEL_OVERRIDE_DO_NOT_USE_THIS` environment variable to override the Cargo channel. As the name suggests, it's not really intended to be used. But you can! Keep in mind that with this approach you only get the unstable features included in the latest stable release (and important fixes for unstable features aren't going to get backported to the stable branch, because this shouldn't be used)

```sh
# Allow unstable options in Cargo, but use stable rustc
__CARGO_TEST_CHANNEL_OVERRIDE_DO_NOT_USE_THIS=nightly cargo build -Z unstable-options
```

Comment: what about doing the same for rustc ?

Comment: @user2284570 `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1` is the rustc equivalent. Although in almost all cases you should just use an actual nightly build instead, using `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP` is essentially always a Bad Idea.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73452457)