# How to enable nightly features on stable builds?

Tags: rust, nightly-build

I need to use [a deprecated project](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum) which does no longer runs using newer versions of stable versions of rustc, but which requires nightly features for being able to use avx512 in order to be able to complete in an acceptable time frame.

The past stable builds of the rust compiler are found in GitHub but where to find past nightly toolchain builds ?

Comment: I believe nightly builds are from the master branch of the rust-lang/rust project on github -- you could build one of those yourself.

Comment: @cdhowie the master branch doesn t build fine. So I looked for binaries and since the a binary for the last master branch can always be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download old nightlies. For example `rustup toolchain install nightly-2018-10-26`, downloads the nightly for 1.30.0 (I'm not sure, just typed the date on the announcement post + 1 day because the exact date didn't have a toolchain available for me).

There's also an option to use features on stable builds. **Do not use that**, it is intended for development of rustc itself, but if you set the environment variable `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1` rustc will allow unstable features on stable builds.

Comment: But where I can find old nightly versions numbers ?

Comment: @user2284570 This is by date, so you need to find a date when the code compiled.