# Using nightly features on stable

Tags: rust

The standard library frequently uses nightly and experimental features on the stable toolchain.

E.g. expanding `#[derive(Debug)]` contains nightly/experimental functionality.

I want to make a crate that expands standard library functionality introducing `u1` `u2`, `u3`, etc. types  this requires `#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end(_)]` and `#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start(_)]` which requires `#![feature(rustc_attrs)]`.

How could I mimic the behaviour of the standard library and allow using nightly features on stable?

---

I am aware of questions on the same topic [How to enable nightly features on stable builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452457/how-to-enable-nightly-features-on-stable-builds) which notes `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1` as a possibility but it doesn't provide an example and I haven't been able to figure out how to use this for my use case.

Comment: Just use nightly lol, I thought everyone does that…

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

If you publish a crate that uses unstable features, then users of the crate must use a nightly version to build it. The standard library is privileged, you cannot do the same in your own crate.

Comment: Specifically, it _is_ possible to mimic std behavior (by using `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP`, which is highly discouraged) but it won't be opaque to your users, they will have to set the environment variable.